# D3 Brush Custom Handles null selection visibility

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to figure out how to have custom brush handles highlight data in a range equal to a single value, which seems to result in a null selection.

Here the Plunkr I recreated on one of Mike Bostock's examples. It's in Angular 2/ionic, so if that's an issue, please go here to view his example's plain javascript. The primary thing I edited was commenting out where he hides the custom handles with css when there is a null selection.

```
if (s == null) {
    //handle.attr("display", "none");
    //circle.classed("active", false);
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/tRyhlJ

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4349545

If you look in the plunkr example, you can see that if you click and let go the brush is still a perfect sphere, with the line where you clicked. Instead if disappearing, I want the brush handles to stay... and not cause errors when you click to expand the handles.

[image]

The error I am currently getting, and can't seem to find a workaround, is this:
[image]

How do I gracefully ignore this internal d3 error and continue on letting my selection expand?

I've tried all sorts of things like turning pointer-events off when it's in this state, and manually unhiding/resizing the default handles, to no avail. Every time, when I click the handles I get this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there's no "clean" way to deal with it. The reason is that a single click defines a range whose size is 0, which the brush considers an empty range (see [source](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush/blob/master/src/brush.js#L113)) and so it purposely nullifies the selection (see [source](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush/blob/master/src/brush.js#L440)).

That all means that unless you create your own version of d3-brush to do what you want, there's no way to have an empty selection that's not null nor a way to render a brush for an empty selection.

There's one workaround I can think of: when you detect an empty selection (where `s == null`) use `brush.move` to set the selection to *something*. That *something* would have to be a range whose size is not 0 (because if you make it 0 then d3, again, would consider that an empty selection and nullify it). To make a non-zero selection that looks like a zero-sized selection (which it has to be, because it's being defined by a single click event) you'd have to make it a tiny selection, eg `[123, 123.0001]`. Instead of 123, you need to know the mouse position of the click, which you can get using `d3.mouse`. Putting it all together, it looks like this:

```
if (s == null) {
  var mousex = d3.mouse(this)[0]
  gBrush.call(brush.move, [mousex, mousex+.001]);
}
```

Comment: I've had trouble implementing this in my much more complicated tool... but ultimately I did somewhat like what you suggested. I just required much larger shifts.

It is a shame, that I never had this issue with d3 v3, now with v4 this has been the bane of my existence for my current tool. I appreciate your help with this, helping me finish by my deadline.

Comment: @Cowman, Sorry to hear that you've had to sink a bunch of time to deal with this issue. Thanks for the points! If you have follow up questions, feel free to post them in this comments thread.